# Validation if all input items are floats in Python

Tags: python, validation

in this following code, I tried to create a validation point that validates if all input items are floats (input if of form "`1,2,3,4,b,w,...`"), however I couldn't understand how to do it without hurting the list itself.
the wanted output is `[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]` when all items are floats, or an error message if the didn't answer only numbers.

```
list1_str = input("Enter list1: ")
list1_str1 = list1_str.replace(" ", "").split(",")
for i in list1_str1: 
  if list1_str1[i].isdigit:
    break
  else: print("item is not float")
list1 = [float(i) for i in list1_str1] #turn list to floats
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you saying you want to ignore the wrong values and create a list of valid floats ?

Comment: there are a few typical operations, not sure which you are trying to do: 1) validate list has all floats (leaving list unmodified) or 2) clean list of non-floats.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: @anon01 the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split this into two parts: 1) validate input type and 2) if correct, cast as numeric type:

```
def validate_list(my_list):
    is_valid = all([j.isnumeric() for j in my_list])
    return is_valid

def cast_numeric(my_list):

    if not validate_list(my_list):
        raise ValueError("non-numeric string value found")
    else:
        return [float(j) for j in my_list]


# examples:
l1 = list("12345")
l2 = l1 + ["not a num"]


validate_list(l1) # true
cast_numeric((l1) # [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]


validate_list(l2) # false
cast_numeric((l2) # raises error message
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code.

- `isdigit` is not a property, its a method so call it like `isdigit()`
- You have put a break in your loop, which is not necessary.

See the below code for some versions of things you want to do

```
list1_str = input("Enter list1: ")
list1_str1 = list1_str.replace(" ", "").split(",")

# This is enough to get all the float values.
numericals = [float(num) for num in list1_str1 if num.isdigit()]

# Let'say you want to print a validation message, then it can be 

if not all([num.isdigit() for num in list1_str1]):
    print("Invalid float items found")

#Let's say you want to print the invalid ones as well, then 
wrong_ones = [num for num in list1_str1 if not num.isdigit()]
if wrong_ones and len(wrong_ones) > 0:
    print(f"The items {wrong_ones} are invalid floats in input")
```

Hope this makes it bit clear for you

Comment: `num.isdigit()` will return `False` if the string `num` contains a period, `'1.1'.isdigit() == False` even though `1.1` is a valid float

Comment: @IainShelvington will num.isnumeric() do the job?

Comment: @ShoshanBen-Tzvi try it yourself, what does `'1.1'.isnumeric()` return in a shell? I don't think there is a satisfactory method on the built-in str type unfortunately